# Android Studio: Set ImageView gradient with RemoteView

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an `ImageView` element which I use as the background of my widget, and I'd like to give it a dynamic gradient as the background using RemoteViews.

I know how to set the background color of the image using:

```html
 remoteViews.setInt(R.id.background, "setColorFilter", someColor);
```

But I'm not sure how setting the gradient works.

Tnanks!

Answer (score -1):

Applying gradients directly to an ImageView in a widget using RemoteViews is not supported in Android, given the limited API set that RemoteViews offers for security and performance reasons. Widgets are intended to have a more restrictive set of functionalities to ensure they are lightweight and not resource-intensive.However, there are a few workarounds you could consider:

1. Pre-generated Bitmap: Generate a Bitmap in your service or activity
   that produces the gradient and then sets this as the image resource
   for your ImageView in the RemoteViews.

   ```
   Bitmap gradientBitmap = generateGradientBitmap();
   remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.background, gradientBitmap); In this case, generateGradientBitmap() would be a custom method
   ```

   where you draw your gradient into a Bitmap object.
2. Static Drawable Resources: If you only need a limited set of
   gradients, you can pre-generate gradient drawables and include them
   in your resources. Then, swap these in and out as needed.

   ```
   remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.background, R.drawable.some_predefined_gradient);
   ```
3. Composite Background: You could overlay multiple ImageViews with
   different opacity and colors to simulate a gradient effect. Each
   ImageView would have to be manipulated individually in your service
   or activity.

**None of these methods would allow you to set a gradient directly in the same way that you might in your main app UI, but they offer some alternatives given the limitations of RemoteViews.**

Here is a small example of how to generate a gradient Bitmap in Java:

```
    public Bitmap generateGradientBitmap() {
    int width = 300; // Width in pixels
    int height = 600; // Height in pixels

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    LinearGradient gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, height,
            Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setShader(gradient);

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, paint);

    return bitmap; }
```

You can replace the colors and dimensions with your specific
requirements. Then you can use this Bitmap as mentioned earlier.

Comment: That's very interesting, however, my ImageView doesn't have the rounded corners it used to have. I used your first solution by the way